# Binomial Regression and Grouping Data

Tags: regression, binomial-distribution, binary-data

I'm currently trying to model Data where the dependent variable is either 0 or 1. Binary outcome.

This would be the same as to say the data comes from a binomial distribution B(1, p). So I could use various link functions like probit, logit or log, etc.

In my dataset some rows are completely the same, as far as I understood so far, this would mean that I have to group the data otherwise my X matrix would not be invertible.
R still calculates this regression - is it just throwing out duplicated cases?

Is it better to group the data, if R is throwing out rows, that would mean that some sort of information is lost, about the frequency of these double entries?

And another question regarding the grouping process itself. If I use grouped data, I just have to throw out double rows and record the frequency and use that as weights?

Comment: What do you mean that some rows are the same? What do you mean by grouping the data?

Comment: I mean some rows of my data frame are completely duplicated, such that all x values and the y value for one entry are the same. With grouping I mean recording the relative frequency of these events. But as far as I know but I am unsure I can solve that problem by using weights in R. maybe an example hels if x is small I could have age 6, female, in multiple instances in my data frame with the same outcome variable

Answer (score 0):

This question is unclear. First, "duplicated" in what sense? If data for the same unit accidentally is repeated in the file, you should de-duplicate, but it might as well be two units with the same values. Two or more six year old girls with the same response value is not impossible ... If you do not know which case, it is up to you to investigate and find out.

Assuming the last case, this will not make any problems. The $X$ matrix itself is not inverted so that is not an issue. You can group the identical rows if you want, but it is not necessary.

> R still calculates this regression - is it just throwing out duplicated cases?

R (and I hope other software) will never throw out duplicated rows.

> And another question regarding the grouping process itself. If I use grouped data, I just have to throw out double rows and record the frequency and use that as weights?

With one row per unit, you have Bernoulli data, the response is 0 or 1. With grouped rows, it is Binomial data and the response is now the total number of successes, you must also have the total number of units grouped together as another variable. Let this variables be `x, n` . One way of specifying the response with the R formula language is now

```r
cbind(x, n-x) ~  ...
```